# Creating a new entity with existing entity type

Tags: database, eav, address, attribute-set, entities

I am fairly new with Magento and not sure if answer to this is very trivial, but looking at available help through search. I was not able to figure out the right way.

For a solution, I am building with Magento I want to add a address for a new entity, which i have created (say `Store` entity - Multistore setup). My initial thought was to user existing address entity created by Magento base but then realized that it's more specific to customer entity (table name: `customer_address_entity`). So I decided to create a new entity with name `store_address_entity`.

However, the `store_address_entity` attributes are very similar to `customer_address_entity` and there is no point of repeating the attributes and was wondering, If there is any better way to do this. I mean

- Can I create `store_address_entity` with `customer_address_entity` type?
- Or Use same attribute set for `shop_address_entity` as for `customer_address_entity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a store_address_entity, including all the other tables `_varchar`, `_int`, etc. And then copy (create) all the attributes as for `customer_address_entity`
2. you can't use the same attributeset for the entity, because attribute sets are nailed to one entity_type.

But if you know the attributes and they don't change, you should think about a flat table.

Comment: If we need to create a separate entity then i see a redundancy here. I thought there will be a better way to do this. Do you also think same?

Comment: Yes it is somehow a redundency, but that's the way to do it in magento :)

Comment: Also, I can see one column in customer_address_entity table, which says 'attribute_set_id'. Can't we create similar table for store_address_entity and specify this as 2? which is attribute set id for customer_address_entity attributes. To avoid duplication of attributes.

Comment: Ok let me be clear here: YES you can. You can do everything we are talking about a turing-complete programming language. But you get a whole world of work, because there are dependencies no one of us is aware of. And you don't want to hack foreign key dependencies in a database :-). Clone all the attributes.

Comment: Or don't do it, go down the dark path. I'm sure we can both learn a lot, please report about it :-)

Comment: Tried adding values in my 'store_address_entity' table with mentioning 'customer_address_entity' attribute set but it turns out that Magento reads 'eav_attribute' table to figure out attribute to entity mapping. Which originally points to 'customer_address_entity'. So even after i added the records in database, they weren't showing up in view.

Comment: How ever when i added a new attribute with setting 'attribute_set_id' to attribute set created for 'store_address_entity', it worked fine. So, I think i have to add the same attributes for my 'shop_address_entity' also. :(